# SQL Server performance for tables having large number of columns

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2008-r2, performance, query-performance

I have a requirement where I need to create a table with about 600 columns. Out of 600 columns about 200 columns will be XML columns. Other column will be of other datatypes such as `int`, `varchar`, `nvarchar` etc.

Also about 50% XML column will have about 40 to 60 rows and other will have less number of rows. The entire table will have about 2000 to 3000 rows. Theoretically SQL allows maximum of 1024 columns. But what will be the performance in my scenario? Does this design will effect performance?

Also does SQL Server have limitation for row size?

Comment: "Does this design will effect performance?" Sure, the design will have an effect on performance. Will it be better or worse?  Well, it kind of depends on what other design you had in mind. It also depends on how you intend to use/query the data.

Comment: Row size is limited to 8060 bytes - except things like `XML` and `(N)VARCHAR(MAX)` column - those can "overflow" into additional pages. Those overflows are pretty bad on performance, however...

Answer (score 1):

If a table has 600 columns it is a very good idea to review the database design. You could move several columns into separate tables, especially the ones with 98% and more NULL values.

Also you will run into trouble if your row does not fit into a single page any more. (see [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186981%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).)

Comment: I don't think that the 8k limit applies to XML columns (if you mean this about the other, 400 columns, ok.)

Comment: It also doesn't apply to VARCHAR(MAX). They are still very likely to encounter row-overflows nevertheless.

Comment: @Twinkles I think 8K limit does not apply to varchar(255) also. see this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chadboyd/archive/2007/02/24/row-sizes-exceeding-8060-bytes-in-sql-2005.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0

Comment: Depends how you look at it. Having VARCHAR(x) columns will allow the data to be inserted, but you will end up with row-overflows and they have an effect on performance.